# How to update existing custom data from google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics.js

I am trying to send large amount of custom data with google analytics. This can be achieve, but my use-case is, after we set custom data in google analytics, we need to update those data, which is previously stored. Any idea or any inbuilt method available for it?

Answer (score 2):

Custom data can be overwritten (excluding Refund data)
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014980?hl=en&utm_id=ad

I tested it. I've uploaded cost data for source/medium and date. And then I've uploaded another file and data was overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update data in GA, but you can use filters. For intance, try to build your custom filter using regular expressions